# How can I do a join using the same table with JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I wrote this query with MySQL and it works:

```
select c.*
from macchine.check_list c
join (select pratica, documentazione, max(versione) as versione
      from macchine.check_list
      group by pratica, documentazione) c2
  on c.pratica = c2.pratica
  and c.documentazione = c2.documentazione
  and c.versione = c2.versione;
```

then I tried to move this query on my web app, using JPA repository:

```
@Query("select t1 from CheckList as t1 join "
        + "(select pratica, documentazione, max(versione) as versione from CheckList group by pratica, documentazione) as t2 "
        + "on t1.pratica = t2.pratica  and "
        + "t1.documentazione = t2.documentazione and "
        + "t1.versione = t2.versione")
```

but it doesn't work, because I know, that ot create a join with JPA repository you have to do someting like:

```
form table1 t1 join t1.table2 t2 on etc.
```

But in this case I need the join on the same table, so how can I do that?

Comment: But you're *not* joining the same table (in your original query).  You're joining an inline view of an aggregate query involving that table.  That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: and JPQL does NOT do a JOIN to a subquery, as any reputable JPA doc would tell you

Comment: @NeilStockton ok, so my question is: Is there a way to do that? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved adding `nativeQuery = true`.

So this is my query:

```
@Query(value = "select t1.* from macchine.check_list as t1 join "
        + "(select pratica, documentazione, max(versione) as versione from macchine.check_list group by pratica, documentazione) as t2 "
        + "on t1.pratica = t2.pratica  and "
        + "t1.documentazione = t2.documentazione and "
        + "t1.versione = t2.versione where t1.pratica = :pratica", nativeQuery = true)
```

Just to be clear this is my table:

```
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | documentazione | pratica | versione | ....... |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 1  | 1              | 1       | 1        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 2  | 2              | 1       | 1        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 3  | 3              | 1       | 1        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 4  | 1              | 1       | 2        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

and using this query the result is this:

```
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | documentazione | pratica | versione | ....... |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 4  | 1              | 1       | 2        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 2  | 2              | 1       | 1        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 3  | 3              | 1       | 1        |         |
+----+----------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support `JOIN`ing an inline view.  The main alternative (in both JPQL and SQL) to filtering results via such a join is filtering them via a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t1
from CheckList t1
where t1.versione = (
  select max(versione)
  from CheckList t2
  where t2.pratica = t1.pratica
    and t2.documentazione = t1.documentazione
)
```

Comment: But if I do that I can't extract all rows, but just those with versione equals to max(versione)

Comment: Well yes, @Teo.  And that's exactly what your original SQL query does, too.  It is the entire visible effect of the `JOIN` there.

Comment: JPQL (= JPA Query Language) is the language in which JPA queries are expressed, @Teo.  You use it directly in your `@Query` annotations.

Comment: With my query I get all row inside my table, and if there are more than 1 row with the same pratica and documentazione I get only the one with the maximum versione

Comment: So no, @Teo, your query *doesn't* get all the rows in your table. Exactly as you say, it gets all those whose `versione` is equal to the maximum for its (`pratica`, `documentazione`) values.  And that is the same thing the query I've presented does.  If you can't see that by analyzing my query, then maybe a database project is not the best kind for you right now.

Comment: No, it's not true... I have tested it on mysql and as I said I get all rows, and if and if there are more rows with the same column I used the versione.. I can't show you a screen shot now, but I'm sure.. As I said I tested it on my database

Comment: We seem to be having some kind of miscommunication, @Teo.  Code does not lie.  Your SQL creates an inline view, associated with identifier `c2`, that contains the maximum `versione` for each distinct `(pratica, documentazione)` pair.  The subsquent join then eliminates from among the `c1` rows each one having a lesser `versione` than the maximum for its own `(pratica, documentazione)` pair.  The remaining `c1` rows form the results.  The query I present achieves exactly the same results via a different, JPQL-supported mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view from your subselect in MySQL then map that view to Java entity and add necessary mapping in `CheckList`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns(
{
    @JoinColumn(name="pratica"),
    @JoinColumn(name="documentazione"),
    @JoinColumn(name="versione")
}
private MaxCheckList maxCheckList;

@Query("select t1 from CheckList as t1 join maxCheckList t2")
```